# Длинное, среднее и короткое тире

Tags: пунктуация

Я работаю в газете и постоянно сталкиваюсь с тем, что в печатном тексте при верстке приходится исправлять короткое тире на длинное (путем нажатия Alt+0151). При этом на длинное тире заменяется все, что не дефис.
Однако существует еще среднее тире.
Так вот, мне интересно, в каких случаях нужно длинное, а в каких среднее тире и почему на компьютерной клавиатуре предусмотрен только дефис?

Comment: А я просто заменил в ворде сочетание клавиш контрол+дефис = тире.

Answer (score 5):

Тире делятся на **пунктуационные** (длинные с пробелами, которые ставят между словами) и **цифровые** (они же короткие, хотя сама черточка среднего размера, если сравнивать с пунктуационным тире и дефисом; цифровые тире без пробелов и ставятся только между числами).

Третьего вида тире не существует (это дефис), просто в некоторых шрифтах тире и дефис совпадают по размеру, что очень неудобно для читателя. Я лично таких шрифтов не понимаю.

На компьютерной клавиатуре предусмотрен и дефис, и оба тире (для ворда: Ctrl + минус, Ctrl + Alt + минус).

Comment: Тат, а как быть на этом форуме? Как мне ставить тире? Лично я ставлю дефис вместо тире, отделяя его пробелами (кнопка после ноля на клавиатуре).

Comment: На форуме вордовские команды не работают, но можно скопировать правильное тире из вордовского файла и вставить в ответ: —

Comment: В том и дело, что не получается. Вместо этого получаются другие символы.

Answer (score 5):

Думаю, Вам интересно будет почитать советы редактора и корректора:

http://www.litsite.ru/2010/12/19/text-word/

Основные правила набора дефисов и тире (для последних — с учётом вошедших в практику "поправок" к академическим правилам) таковы:

— дефис ставится: в сложных словах (типа "ярко-красный"); при порядковых числительных, записанных арабскими цифрами с наращением (например, "11-й класс"). Дефис набирается без отбивок; исключение составляют дефисы в словах, набранных в разрядку                      ( например, "т ё м н о - к р а с н ы й");

— длинное тире ставится: в начале абзаца; между самостоятельными словами (первое из этих слов может быть и со знаком препинания: с точкой, запятой и так далее). Длинное тире рекомендуется отбивать с обеих сторон; исключение — если стоит в начале абзаца: тогда, естественно, отбивается только справа;

— короткое тире рекомендуется ставить: между словами и цифрами, обозначающими диапазон (например, "10–20", "XX–XXI", Москва–Париж ); в значении "минус" перед цифрой (например, "–2 градуса"); между цифрами в телефонных номерах. Короткое тире набирается без отбивок.

http://www.litsite.ru/2011/01/15/tire/

Comment: Интересно, откуда автор взяла эту информацию. Она предлагает писать "Москва–Париж", а между тем короткое тире (цифровое, без пробелов) между словами не ставится и должно быть "Москва — Париж". Автор пишет, что длинное тире в начале абзаца отбивается только справа, а между тем такой способ оформления прямой речи называется "оформление с абзаца" и по определению предполагает отбивку слева. То, о чем она пишет, действительно встречается в печати, только непонятно, откуда ноги растут. Возможно, из старого-престарого издания Мильчина.

Comment: Может, Мильчина, а может, это идёт сближение русской и европейской типографий, это там используется длинное и короткое тире, а у нас только дефис и тире, ну, и плюс математический знак минус, о нём речи нет.

Answer (score 4):

Я опускаю подробности насчет двух тире и дефиса, ***tat*** всё сказала.
А правила употребления - у Людмилы.

Добавлю только то, что у программистов "среднее тире" - это наше короткое, а "короткое тире" - дефис, он же минус. Это не должно путать, но желательно все-таки эту терминологию за пределами программисткой тусовки не выносить. С другой стороны в советских традициях при наборе формул для "бумажной" печати минус обычно имел ту же длину, что и длинное тире, но так было далеко не везде. Видимо в стремлении избежать путаницы программисты и придумали свои названия для трех тире, чем еще больше все  запутали.

Я насчет использования символов в среде, где это не предусмотрено напрямую - типа форума.

Тут вот какая штука. Чтобы проставить тире (дефис) нужного вида нужно иметь три составляющие: возможность ввода нужного символа с клавиатуры, поддержка его средой сервера приложения и возможности вашего браузера по его визуализации, включая поддержку вашей операционной системой. С первым сейчас проблем обычно нет на компьютерах, но могут быть на планшетах и, разумеется, смартофонах, для них это проблемы вечные и непреодолимые. 
Что касается серверных приложений (среда самого форума), тут обычно поддерживается длинное тире, но короткое "по умолчанию" предлагается заменять на дефис. На мой взгляд это вполне разумное решения, у них, как вы понимаете, совершенно разное смысловое назначение, но что касается визуального воспроизведения, то их роль сходна - они ставятся, когда надо зрительно соединить (а не разъединить) части по обе стороны короткого тире или дефиса. Но при необходимости всегда можно вомпольздваться альтернативным вводом (если ваше устройство позволяет). 
В виндуз это делается с помощью т.н. Alt-ввода.
Дефис - минус.
Короткое (среднее) тире – Alt+0150
Длинное тире — Alt+0151

Только учтите, что тут вступает в действие третье необходимое условие из названных мной выше. Среда визуализации вашего компьютера должна поддерживать нужное воспроизведение нужного символа. Обычно это касается "среднего" тире, оно воспроизводится как "короткое", что, как сказал, мне представляется вполне оправданным для экранного чтения.

Ну а в тех случаях, когда такой выразительности не требуется, все тире и дефисы можно заменить на короткое, в крайнем случае, для эстетов, длинное передавать двумя минусами.

Вот так: "поезд *Москва **--** Петербург*".

Comment: «Добавлю только то, что у программистов "среднее тире" - это наше короткое, а "короткое тире" - дефис, он же минус» — интересно, а откуда у вас такие данные?

Comment: @ensovet Из первоисточника. Программист к вашим услугам. ))) Но ещё есть сайт Арт. Лебедева, источник, конечно, не слишком авторитетный, но таки есть.Могу только оговорится, что подобная узкопрофессиональная терминология обычно подвержена  изменениям и быстро устаревает. Возможно, за последние лет двадцать что-то и изменилось.

Comment: Я программист ещё с тех времён, когда компьютеры были большими, и вот сегодня с изумлением узнал, что у программистов, оказывается, есть какое-то тире. Расскажите, пожалуйста, где оно применяется, в каких-таких языках программирования? Откуда вы вообще это взяли?? Сразу скажу, что Лебедев не аргумент - это не программист, а модный дизайнер, который с программированием даже рядом не стоял. Или вы считаете, что верстка на компьютере - это тоже типа программирование?

Comment: @freim Ну вы еще молоды. Я программист с тех еще времен, когда их не было. Были ЭЦВМ и МСС.

Comment: @freim  Что касается тире. А какие именно тире вы знаете? Хотя, если вы говорите о языках программирования, значит вы не слишком поняли суть вопроса. Всё обсуждение касалось машинной вкрстки, компьтерного набора  и прочих вещей, с языками связанными весьма слабо.

Comment: Знаете, еще не факт, что вы меня старше. Что такое МСС я не знаю, но ЭЦВМ-то тут при чём? На разных ЭЦВМ я и начинал, и никаких тире там тоже не помню.

Comment: @freim вы молоды потому, что сразу лезете пиписьками мериться. Как программист вы не можеты быть меня старше. Ну если, конечно, вы не Америки начинали. А вот то, что вы настаиваеие на своем прочтении написанного тмною - это из другой области. Один раз повторю. К язвкам программированич это не имеет ниекакого отношения. Речь идет о компьютерной верстке. Если ваша сфера понимания ограничена  набором символов клавиатуры и барабанного печатающего устройства, то да, там никаких "других" тире и нету.

Comment: МСС - машинно-счетная станция. Стыдно не знать таких вещей человеку, выдающему себя за живую историю.

Comment: За живую историю вроде вы себя выдаете, нет? Впрочем, по теме все ясно - программированием вы называете верстку на компьютере. Довольно оригинально, этак любая секретарша с вордом у нас программист. Но если вы хотите считать себя программистом - на здоровье.

Comment: @freim *программированием вы называете верстку на компьютере* -  Эк куда вас занесло-то. ))))   А нде я такое сказал, не покажете? Впрочем, двизок уже ругается, пора и честь знать. Уважайте труд модероаторов.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96861/discussion-between-behemothus-and-freim).

Answer (score 2):

0151 — тире (—)
0150 — минус (–)
0171 — «
0187 — »
0176 — °
0149 — •
0160 — неразрывный пробел
0133 — …
0169 — ©
0174 — ®
0153 — ™
0177 — ±
Выучить один раз — и нет проблемы. В стандартной виндовской утилите *Character map* есть подсказки.
А для планшетов и телефонов есть клавиатуры с человеческой типографикой. *JBack*, к примеру.

Comment: Проверила — с «Alt» и включенным «Num Lock» работает. Спасибо.

Comment: Мне в юности довелось работать в издательстве, где были такие упраздненные ныне должности, как корректор и редактор. Моими старшими коллегами были прожженные тетки старой школы. Они ещё гранки вычитывали. Мне очень быстро отбили пальцы линейкой за типографические ошибки. Поставить "кавычки" вместо «кавычек» было всё равно, что написать «карова», а уж дефис поставить вместо тире считалось вопиющим актом вандализма против русского языка. А в современных журналах можно и предлог в конце строчки увидеть. Ничего.